# How to jump back from find-tag in Emacs

Tags: emacs, etags

I'm using `find-tag` function <kbd>M-.</kbd> to jump to function definition, how can I jump back to previous location?

Comment: `C-u C-SPC` locally, `C-x C-SPC` globally

Comment: what function was in `C-x C-SPC` because I overwrite it with custom `jump-to-mark` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch to original buffer after chasing tags in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150719/switch-to-original-buffer-after-chasing-tags-in-emacs)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

<kbd>M-.</kbd> calls `xref-find-definitions` in recent versions of Emacs. I use <kbd>M-,</kbd>, which is bound to `xref-pop-marker-stack`, to return back. You can even use it to recursivelly return from a deeper search.

In older Emacs versions, <kbd>M-.</kbd> was bound to `find-tag` which worked similarly. The inverse function was `pop-tag-mark` by default bound to <kbd>M-*</kbd>.

Comment: Maybe the second part of the answer of using `M-,` should be mentioned first since it's the one applicable to recent versions (the suggestion in the first part doesn't work anymore).

Comment: @daaku: better?