# how to get back the origional file after using "find file at point" in emacs

Tags: emacs

> what is the bindkey I can use to get the origional file back after executing the >command "find-file-at-point" in emacs?
>   Thanks
>   Howard

Comment: `C-x k` to kill new buffer or `C-x b` to switch to the previous buffer?

Comment: What @ArkadiuszDrabczyk said. If the file's buffer was not killed then just switch to it (`C-x b`). If it was killed then reopen the file again (`C-x C-f`).

Comment: Unless you want to *kill* the current buffer, you can generalise your question to "how can I get back to where I was before" when the window configuration has changed (including simply which buffers are displayed in which windows) for any reason, and a very useful solution to that problem is `winner-mode`.  E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152971/324105.

Comment: Beyond that, there are many tools for buffer management.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394289/324105 has useful answers, and a bunch of related Q&As can also be found in the "Linked" sidebar on that page.